# How do I add a key/value pair into my hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am stuck in the below exercise.

Instructions:

Inside your when "add" block, remove the puts "Added!" statement.

In its place, prompt the user for a movie title. Save the result in a new variable called title. (Your code already has an example of how to do this!)

Next, prompt the user for the rating of the movie. Save that in a new variable called rating.

Add that movie/rating pair to the movies hash and puts a message indicating the pair was added. (No need for to_sym or to_i just yet!)

Code:

```
movies = {"good fellas"=> "5"}
  puts "what's your favorite movie?"
  choice=gets.chomp
case choice
  when "add"
    puts "what's the movie you would like to add?"
    title=gets.chomp
    movies[title]
    puts"what's the rating for your selected movie?"
    rating=gets.chomp
    movies[title]=rating
  when "update"
    puts "Updated!"
  when "display"
    puts "Movies!"
  when "delete"
    puts "Deleted!"
else
    puts "Error!"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a key/value pair to a hash can be done like this:

`hash[key] = value`

So in your case:

```
when "add"
  puts "what's the movie you would like to add?"
  title=gets.chomp

  puts "what's the rating for your selected movie?"
  rating=gets.chomp

  movies[title] = rating
  puts "movie added"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Following should be your code**

```
movies = {"good fellas"=> "5"}
puts "what's your favorite movie?"
choice=gets.chomp
case choice
  when "add"
    puts "what's the movie you would like to add?"
    title=gets.chomp
    #movies[title]
    puts"what's the rating for your selected movie?"
    rating=gets.chomp
    movies[title]=rating
  when "update"
    puts "Updated!"
  when "display"
    puts "Movies!"
  when "delete"
    puts "Deleted!"
else
    puts "Error!"
end
```